# How to play next random song of the array of songs

Tags: java, android, arrays, random

I have an array of songs, My app play songs randomly when an activity is open but when the song is finished I would like to play another random song from the array, does anyone can help with it?

```
public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private int songs[];
```

```
songs = new int[] {
    R.raw.track1,
    R.raw.track2,
    R.raw.track3,
    R.raw.track4,
    R.raw.track5,
    R.raw.track6,
    R.raw.track7,
    R.raw.track8,
    R.raw.track9,
    R.raw.track10,
    R.raw.track11,
    R.raw.track12,
    R.raw.track13,
    R.raw.track14,
    R.raw.track15,
    R.raw.track16,
    R.raw.track17,
};


int randomSong =  new Random().nextInt(songs.length);
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, songs[randomSong]);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: what is the problem with the code that you have ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, You need to implement `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener` interface
in your activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private int songs[];
    private int randomSong;
    private Random random = new Random();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        songs = new int[]{
                R.raw.track1,
                R.raw.track2,
                R.raw.track3,
                R.raw.track4,
                R.raw.track5,
                R.raw.track6,
                R.raw.track7,
                R.raw.track8,
                R.raw.track9,
                R.raw.track10,
                R.raw.track11,
                R.raw.track12,
                R.raw.track13,
                R.raw.track14,
                R.raw.track15,
                R.raw.track16,
                R.raw.track17,
        };


        randomSong = getRandom(songs);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, songs[randomSong]);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        randomSong = getRandom(songs);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, songs[randomSong]);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public int getRandom(int[] array) {
        return random.nextInt(array.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: OP is already using the random function

Comment: using a new Random object each time the method is called is a bad idea

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have edited my answer

Comment: @Abhay You have, but you are still creating new Random objects. Add Random random = new Random() as a member of MainActivity and use it instead.

Comment: Thanks for aswering, but it's not working, after the song is finished it doesn't play the next random song. Do I need to call the OnCompletion method inside onCreate? @Abhay Tomar

Comment: @djalmafreestyler you need to set the onCompletionListener both in onCreate() and onCompletion(): mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);

Comment: @O.O.Balance you are right. and thanks for pointing out. I have edited the answer. @djalmaffreestyler just write  `mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);` inside your onCreate() method.

Comment: @AbhayTomar Sorry, I don't see the changes - your code still instantiates new Random objects in two places.

Comment: @O.O.Balance Check it now

Comment: @AbhayTomar in your getRandom() method, you instantiate a new Random object every time it is called. Introducing an int randomSong makes no difference. Instead, declare a private Random random, initialise it once and use it every time in getRandom().

Comment: Applied changes, thanks @O.O.Balance

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a [completion listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener)):

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // Play next song
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a listener to run a callback when the song has finished playing:

```
setOnCompletionListener(MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener listener)
```

Also, to ensure randomness, I strongly recommend not using a new `Random` object each time you need a random number. Rather, declare a variable `random` and use that for all your randomness needs.